# Bash script grabbing specific lines of top

Tags: string, bash

Is it possible to grap specific lines of top within a bash script?

the following command works within command shell, but this does not work within a bash script, i also tried grep

```
echo "             " `top | awk 'NR==7'`
echo "             " `top | awk 'NR==8'`
```

(i also tried this without the back ticks but it produces the same blank text)

Comment: which values in particular do you want to display in your script?

Comment: i want to view all values from line 7 to the next 10 lines, (top 10 processes and header) within a bash script which contains other system related commands

Comment: You may want to [edit] your question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU top, I think the simplest way to do what you want is

```
top -n 1 -b | sed -n '7,17 p'
```

`sed` selects only the 7th to the 17th line from `top` output.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the differences you are observing are due to the interactive nature of `top`.  Consider passing command line parameters to top to disable the interactive aspect of it.  For example, on MAC, here's a command to take a single sample ( and return) with the top 5 processes:

```
top -l 1 -n 5
```

If you want to use awk to select specific lines, let's say 7 through 17 inclusive, try this:

```
top -l 1 | awk 'NR >= 7 && NR <= 17'
```

Comment: I couldn't actually get this command to work, it may be because you said it was mac and i am using Ubuntu at the moment, but i appreciate your time. :)